# Alarmreceiver how to stop the mediaplayer

Tags: android, android-activity

**AlarmReceiver.class**

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

       // Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);


        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
            stopPlaying();
            mp.stop();
        }
        else {
            stopPlaying();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.drawable.aaz);
            mp.start();
        }

}


 private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }}
```

this sets the alarm when the timer is reached then it wil play the audio.

**this code below is from Mainactivity.**

```
private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
        textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                "\n\n***\n"
                        + "Alarm is set@ " + targetCal.getTime() + "\n"
                        + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
```

stop alarm : but the audio is not stopping when this code is triggers the **AlarmReceiver.class**.

**the code below is from Mainactivity**.

```
 private void cancelAlarm() {

            textAlarmPrompt.setText(
                    "\n\n***\n"
                            + "Alarm Cancelled! \n"
                            + "***\n");




            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

make a service to handle the alarm and you can handle it by set your alarm schedule in startService and stop in stopService

Comment: I really appreciate your kind reply sir.  i am new to this , i have so far followed a tutorial and made this app first time also i have added the media code my self without getting help i am eager to learn just want to know more about what to do.     kindly tell me how to use the  ( service ) how do i go around making a simple one please advise as i am very new sir cheers.